# More than one mime-type for intype of mod_ext_filter (text/css and application/javascript)

Tags: apache, perl, mime-types, substitution, mod-filter

I have built a substituion filter that is already working as I expect it. It adds a timestamp to the end of a html file (EOF).

```
ExtFilterDefine testfilter mode=output intype=text/html cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 's|^|qq(\/*) . time() . qq(\*/)|e if$==eof'"
SetOutputFilter testfilter
```

My goal is, to get this run for more than one mime-types. Is there a way to specify the intype of the filter and assign two mime-types at only one filter?

I need `text/css` and `text/js` as mime-type for the intype of my current filter. I am looking for an option without writing the same code twice.

I tried the following, but it is not working and end up at a apache error:

```
ExtFilterDefine testfilter mode=output intype=text/css application/javascript cmd="/usr/bin/perl -pe 's|^|qq(\/*) . time() . qq(\*/)|e if$==eof'"
```

Does somebody as any ideas how to get it run the right way without to much more code?

Comment: Note that `if$==eof` is equivalent to `if $= = eof` where `$=` is the special variable containing the current page length. You probably meant to write `if eof` ?

Comment: Maybe you can you create a custom type with [AddType](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype) that combines the types you need to pass through the filter? Then use that type as `intype` parameter to `ExtFilterDefine`

Comment: @Håkon Hægland:
Nice idea, thank's. Could you give an example for creating a new type that contains two mime-types?